# Could someone explain line endings?

Tags: vim, newline, coding-style, line

The current project I'm working requires me to follow certain procedures to eliminate whitespace in my code. Apparently this has got something to do with line endings since one requirement explicitly tells me to "end all lines with a Unix line ending (\n)".

I code in VIM from the terminal, and I press enter for a new line to write on. Am I missing something here?

What is the reason to keep the code clean from trailing whitespace and using specific types of line breaks?

On a side note, what standard VI/VIM settings do you guys use to adhere to common coding standards?

Sincerely,
Why

Comment: Jeff Atwood can: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different operating systems have different line break conventions.  Unix-like systems prefer `\n` (`LF`); Windows prefers `\r\n` (`CR LF`); pre-OSX Mac OS used `\r` (`CR`).  Maintaining one convention across a project is usually a good idea.

As for trailing whitespace, AFAIK it's just sloppy (may indicate "quick and dirty" reformatting).  In some environments trailing whitespace might also be significant.

Comment: All right, but why is this important? Isn't a new line just a new line?

Comment: Mixing different kinds of newline in the same file, potentially including files `include`d into another file, confuses many compilers and tools.  To humans, a newline is just a newline; but far too many computer programs are too literal for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not everyone on the project codes in VIM, they might be using a windows based IDE which would insert `\r\n` for a new line.
They would have to ensure that their line-endings are correct before committing code, whereas you shouldn't have this problem as vim will use `\n` as its natural line ending.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce this in vim, you can use the `fileformat` option. Setting it to `unix` will make your newlines use `\n`.